# How to open html document in the browser by its Uri

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage

I am saving an html document in the windows azure blob. Now i am trying to open that document by putting its URI in the address bar. But browser redirect me to orbit downloader to download that document. How can i open it by its blob uri? My document blob uri :

```
https://xxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/user/name.html
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the content type of that file to **html**. This is possible using tools like [Azure Storage Explorer](http://davidpallmann.blogspot.be/2011/10/cloud-gourmet-30-minute-meal-static-web.html) (see point 3D) or by using the [SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh225342.aspx)/REST API.

Comment: I have to change the content type while saving that file in the blob?

Comment: Yes. You can also change it later on by changing blob properties (the property you want to change is ContentType).